# solve $\log_3^2(x)-\log_2(x)=2$

Tags: logarithms

The solution for the equation $\log_3^2(x)-\log_3(x)=2$ is

a) $s=\{2,-1\}$; b) $s=\{6,-3\}$; c) $s=\{9, 1/3 \}$; d) $s=\{27, 1/9 \}$; e) $s=\{ 1/6 ,12\}$

It was given in a test at school and I could not solve. I put on wolfram and the answer is not on the options. [Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20log%283%2Cx%29%5E2-log%282%2Cx%29%3D2)

Comment: Yeah, I'm really sorry to inform you that WolframAlpha got it right, and you might have made a typo...

Comment: Probably, one more typo in the book !

Answer (score 5):

From the given options, I guess that you want to solve the following for $x$ : 
$$(\log_3(x))^2-\log_\color{red}{3}(x)=2.$$
Let $t=\log_3(x)$. Then, we have
$$t^2-t-2=0\iff (t-2)(t+1)=0\iff t=2,-1\iff x=3^2,3^{-1}.$$

Comment: To point out the blatantly obvious: this answer assumes that the OP made a typo, and wrote $\log_2$ instead of $\log_3$.

Comment: @anorton: Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

$\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(3)}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}\right)=2$
setting $t=\log(x)$ we get a quadratic equation.